# Calculate sum in while loop to array

Tags: php

When the number 6 is giving I need to calculate till 6: for example: 1+2+3+4+5+6=21. I also need to add the sums of each to an array like: 1+2=3, 1+2+3=6, 1+2+3+4=10, ...

I have tried to make the while loop to be printed and this working fine but nog for array purpose:

```
   <?php
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $i = 1;
  $cal = 0;
  $tussenBerekening = array();

  while ($i <= $number) {
    echo $i;
    $cal = $cal + $i;
    array_push($tussenBerekening, $cal);
    if ($i != $number) {
      echo " + ";
    } else {
      echo " = " . $cal;
    }
    $i++;
  }
?>
```

This is my new code, it prints, but no total sum.

```
<?php
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $i = 2;
  $cal = 0;
  $sum = 1;
  $berekeningen = array();


  while ($i <= $number) {
    $sum .= "+" . $i;
    array_push($berekeningen, $sum);
    $i++;
  }

  print_r($berekeningen);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
$i = 1;
$number = 6;
while ($i <= $number) {
    // generate array with values from 1 to $i
    $array = range(1, $i);
    // if there're more than 1 element in array - output sum
    if (count($array) > 1) {
             // 1+2+... part                // sum of elements of array
        echo implode('+', $array) . ' = ' . array_sum($array) . '<br />';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Nice! That's a really pretty PHP-specific solution. The asker's going to look like a professional old-timer on his assignment :)